# Android: Add new buildType - Unable to find a matching configuration of project

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

Android Studio 3.1, Gradle 4.4

My project hierarchy

```
-app
-common
build.gradle
```

`common` is a android lib for my project.
As result in **settings.gradle**:

```
include ':app', ':common'
```

Here my **app/build.gradle**

```
    buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
                configBuildType(delegate, RELEASE_APP_NAME, null, RELEASE_API_BASE_URL)
                signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            }
            debug {
                configBuildType(delegate, DEBUG_APP_NAME, DEBUG_APP_ID_SUFFIX, DEBUG_API_BASE_URL)
            }
        }

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])   

    implementation project(':common')   
}
```

And my project success build and run. Nice.

Now I want to add new **buildType = "debugTest"**

So here my **app/build.gradle**

```
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            configBuildType(delegate, RELEASE_APP_NAME, null, RELEASE_API_BASE_URL)
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
        debug {
            configBuildType(delegate, DEBUG_APP_NAME, DEBUG_APP_ID_SUFFIX, DEBUG_API_BASE_URL)
        }
        debugTest {

        }
}
```

But now I get error when build project:

```
gradlew clean build
```

Here error messages:

```
WARNING: The option 'android.enableD8' is deprecated and should not be used anymore.
Use 'android.enableD8=true' to remove this warning.
It will be removed in AGP version 3.3.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:lintVitalDebugTest'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugTestRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve project :common.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > Unable to find a matching configuration of project :common:
          - Configuration 'debugApiElements':
              - Required com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'debugTest' and found incompatible value 'debug'.
              - Found com.android.build.api.attributes.VariantAttr 'debug' but wasn't required.
              - Required com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'Aar' and found compatible value 'Aar'.
              - Required org.gradle.usage 'java-runtime' and found incompatible value 'java-api'.
          - Configuration 'debugRuntimeElements':
              - Required com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'debugTest' and found incompatible value 'debug'.
              - Found com.android.build.api.attributes.VariantAttr 'debug' but wasn't required.
              - Required com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'Aar' and found compatible value 'Aar'.
              - Required org.gradle.usage 'java-runtime' and found compatible value 'java-runtime'.
          - Configuration 'releaseApiElements':
              - Required com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'debugTest' and found incompatible value 'release'.
              - Found com.android.build.api.attributes.VariantAttr 'release' but wasn't required.
              - Required com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'Aar' and found compatible value 'Aar'.
              - Required org.gradle.usage 'java-runtime' and found incompatible value 'java-api'.
          - Configuration 'releaseRuntimeElements':
              - Required com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'debugTest' and found incompatible value 'release'.
              - Found com.android.build.api.attributes.VariantAttr 'release' but wasn't required.
              - Required com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'Aar' and found compatible value 'Aar'.
              - Required org.gradle.usage 'java-runtime' and found compatible value 'java-runtime'.
```

Answer (score 0):

In your project called "common", in build.gradle, add build type definition you just added to the main project. Like so:

```
android {
    buildTypes {
        release {}
        debug {}
        debugTest {}
    }
}
```

Comment: I use another approach: in app/build.gradle          debugTest {
           matchingFallbacks = ['debug', 'release']
        }

Comment: I used this approach too, but in some cases it doesn't work correctly (yet?). I think it's failing with more flavors and dimensions.